# JHipster: After generating an entity, how can I access a custom java function in my EntityResource from the frontend?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I have been using JHipster a little bit and have a specific question.

I have an entity with all my back-end, CRUD operations generated by JHipster. I have customized my CRUD operations and have been able to add to the Resource to fit my needs, no problem with that.

However, in one of the forms that I have for the ADD operations, I need a button that would call the backend, do some work, and send the result back to the front-end. This needs to happen without submitting the form.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="test()" class="btn btn-info">Test</button>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.test = (function () {
        alert("test");
        MyEntity.test();
    });
```

Finally, my backend code in my resource java file:

```
public void testDatabase() {
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

I know that I will eventually have to return a ResponseEntity type, in order to send some data back to my front-end, but right now, I cannot even get my backend method to be called from the test function that I have defined in my controller.

What would be the best approach in order to achieve this, in the context of JHipster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about 2 different problems, both leading to a lack of experience in the underlying frameworks.

the first problem is your not submitting form....this is already discussed by a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297340/jhipster-how-to-call-a-controller-function-from-a-button-without-submitting-th).

the second problem is your backend code, which I don't know where you putted in, wether you annotated it and so on...

generally you **should always** work with `ResponseEntity`, because you are building REST and you need the power to work with the HTTP protocol, in particular with response codes. Next....you **never** System.out.println in spring....if you want to have output, you use Logger, for response types you should return something...like

```
public String test() {
    return "test";
}
```

or

```
public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("test");
    }
```

general, you should review some more material to both spring boot and angularjs, then JHipster will help you to find a working way to wire things

Best regards